# Microsoft services to send SMS to phone

Tags: azure, power-automate

I am working on a Flow app lately and I wonder if we have any Microsoft services available to send SMS texts to phone without using connectors like Twilio. I have tried Twillio and it works good. But I would like to know if there are any free/paid services available from Microsoft to send text messages.

Comment: When you googled "azure sms service", did you get any results?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. For any specific problem you are having please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also, be sure to take the https://stackoverflow.com/tour (you get a badge!)

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: no, there is not. You have to use a service like Twilio.